# Хороший мануал по jQuery, для нубов истессна

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем здравствуйте! Собственно вопрос - где есть хороший мануал по сабжу, желательно практический? Т.е. такие вкусные штуки как открытие новых окон с затемнением, работа с изображениями, скрытие / показ областей текста, и т.д.

Дико извиняюсь за тупой вопрос :)

Comment: http://jquery.com/ не?

Comment: @AlexWindHope, сказано же, "для нубов". Нубы не знают английского. Им сюда: http://jquery-docs.ru/

Answer (score 6):

По-английски:

- [Tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials)
- [Learning JQuery](http://www.learningjquery.com/)
- [51+ Best of jQuery Tutorials and Examples](http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/51-best-of-jquery-tutorials-and-examples.html)

По-русски:

- [JSToolBox](http://www.jstoolbox.com/category/jquery/)
- [jQuery и другое...](http://www.linkexchanger.su/category/jquery)
- [JQuery Page 2 Page](http://jquery.page2page.ru/)

Answer (score 6):

Да, книга Бибо и Каца [**jQuery. Подробное руководство по продвинутому JavaScript, 2-е издание**](http://www.books.ru/shop/books/827253?partner=81046) однозначно рулит. Лучше книги по jQuery (и для новичка и для профессионала) пока просто нет. Даже равной ей нет - она "выше" всех остальных "на голову". Не нудная - читается легко, отличный учебник и неплохой справочник. Однозначно лучшая книга о jQuery на русском (на данный момент во всяком случае). Имхо, маст хэв каждый кто использует эту библиотеку или хочет ее использовать.
Недавно вышло 2-е издание. Один из авторов - разработчик в команде jQuery.

Comment: Хорошая книга для профи и медиум, но, имхо, не то, с чего надо начинать нубам

Answer (score 5):

Я начал с этого: [jQuery для начинающих // JavaScript](http://anton.shevchuk.name/javascript/jquery-for-beginners/).

Answer (score 2):

Мне очень нравится вот этот ресурс: [Руководство jQuery](http://slyweb.ru/jquerymain/) - всё по-русски
там сейчас помимо этого есть и хелп по другим разделам.

> jQuery документация на русском включает основы, методы и функции для работы с элементами, методы поиска элементов, матоды для работы с ajax, пользовательские функции анимации и многое другое, содержащееся на официальном сайте [jquery.com](http://jquery.com), все функции, методы jquery объясняются с помощью "живых" примеров jquery.  Дополнительные разделы сайта - Статьи по PHP, jQuery, CSS и HTML, JAVASCRIPT.

Answer (score 2):

Перед изучением jQuery советую попробовать VanillaJS !

Очень мощный фреймворк, набирающий популярность. [Вот тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/150594/) подробно описано.

Возможности его реально не ограничены.

Изучив его - понять jQuery Вам ничего не будет стоить.

---

Кроме шуток.

По сути, вы хотите научиться "круто" анимировать блоки и навешивать события, угадал? Познайте js, хорошенько поработайте с DOM - после этого http://docs.jquery.com/ - вам будет более чем достаточно для понимания работы jq и для "крутой" анимации блоков.

> Т.е. такие вкусные штуки как открытие новых окон с затемнением, работа с изображениями, скрытие / показ областей текста, и т.д.

Для этого просто разберите соответствующие примеры [вот тут](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_examples.asp), например. Поняв, какой параметр за что отвечает, сможете легко создавать подобные скрипты с нужным вам результатом.

Серьезно, я знаю людей, которые так покупали книжки по jq, но они просто не могут их читать, потому что не имеют даже представления о том, что такое DOM и не знают даже синтаксиса js.

Answer (score 2):

Отличный учебник от Антона Шевчука [Учебник "jQuery для начинающих"](http://anton.shevchuk.name/jquery-book/)

Answer (score 1):

Мне понравилась книга jquery in action (есть на русском) Бибо и Каца, для новичка будет очень интересно и с подробными примерами. А как справку можно использовать оф сайт с апи и http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php (апи на русском)

Answer (score 1):

Мне очень нравится вот эта: [jQuery: Novice To Ninja](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/jquery1/)

Answer (score 1):

[Русская документация](http://jquery-docs.ru/)

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/ - довольно толковое объяснение всех функций Жуквери. Примеры кода тоже вполне юзабельны.
[http://plugins.jquery.com/](http://api.jquery.com/) - сборник примеров кода, обычно без объяснения. :)
Ну, и гугловский запрос "оптимизация jQuery" тоже еще в силе.