# Почему не срабатывает метод "delay" (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

```js
$(".user-panel-header .user-panel__head").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass("user-panel__head_active");
  $(".user-panel__user-menu").slideToggle(500);
  if ( $(".user-panel-header .user-panel__head").hasClass("user-panel__head_active") ) {
    $(".user-panel-header .user-panel__head").css({"background":"#5f8898"});
  } else {
    $(".user-panel-header .user-panel__head").delay(500).css("background","transparent");
  }
});
```

Comment: Я же уже видел этот вопрос...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) устанавливает задержку перед выполнением очередной функции в очереди.
Вы можете поставить свою функцию в очередь с помощью [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/).

```
$(".user-panel-header .user-panel__head").delay(500).queue(function (next) { 
  $(this).css("background", "transparent");
  next();
});
```

Такой способ может оказаться более удобным, чем `.setTimeout()`, в случае если нужна более сложная манипуляция с элементами. Например,

```
$(selector)
    .delay(500)
    .queue(function (next) { /* что-то делаем */ })
    .delay(500)
    .fadeOut();
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Не подскажешь где лучше всего учить jQuery?
(Русскоязычный ресурс)

Comment: [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/17203) есть полезные ссылки

Answer (score 2):

Вот выдержка из документации jQuery:

> Команда .delay() позволяет установить время задержки выполнения
>   следующих функций анимационных эффектов в очереди для каждого элемента
>   набора jQuery

В твоем случае тебе нужно сделать просто задержку выполнения кода через

```
setTimeout(function() {
     $(".user-panel-header .user-panel__head").css("background","transparent");
}, 500)
```

Comment: Это тоже ответ, но который я отметил "правильным" ближе к контексту jQuery.
Спасибо!