# Как передать изменение класса через toggleClass() с задержкой? jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, есть такой код:

```
$(this).parents('.menu').toggleClass(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        setTimeout(y = function () {
            return 'active';
        }, 1000);
        return y;
    } else {
        return 'active';
    }
});
```

Не срабатывает setTimeout, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: .delay() не работает на .toggleClass()

Comment: [Почему не срабатывает метод delay](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/681715)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему вас не устраивает подобный такому вариант?

```js
$("div").on("click", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("div").toggleClass("red");
  }, 1000);
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue
}

div.red {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Ну и есть еще такой вариант, с использованием `jquery-ui`, но тут уже решать вам, что важнее, объем страниц и переписывание кода под этот вариант, или то, что я предложил выше. Ну и плюс тут возможно только плавное изменение, а не скачкообразное, по крайней мере я не нашел такой возможности.

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("big-blue", 1000, "easeOutSine");
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.big-blue {
  background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, да, так работает, но надо будет много переписывать))

Comment: @Виктор ну тогда это стоило указать в вопросе, но вообще это верный и рабочий вариант, что главное :) Ну и, если вам интересно просто поменять значение в `toggleClass()`, ради меньшего редактирования кода, то вряд ли это получится решить так, как вы попробовали. Я бы тогда скорее смотрел на `animate()`, это вызовет чуть больше замен, но меньше, чем, я предполагаю, при предложенном мной варианте.

Comment: Ну да, мне интересно именно как работает передача функции в toggleClass() , ведь по сути передавать функцию туда можно https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ и все работает кроме таймера, что меня удивило, спасибо за ответ еще раз)

Comment: @Виктор я вам еще один вариант в ответе на вопрос подкинул, посмотрите, может он подойдет больше.

Comment: Спасибо большое, это хороший вариант, но подгружать туда UI только ради этого очень нежелательно, перепишу код лучше

Comment: @Виктор, ага, ну как я там и написал, сомнительно преимущество подключения библиотеки взамен редактирования кода.

Answer (score 1):

И правда, .delay() почему-то не срабатывает, вот по быстрому что-то накидал :

```js
$("#test").click(function() {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(self).toggleClass('invisible');
  }, 2000)

});
```

```css
.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" style="background-color:red">test div</div>
```

На щет того, что ваш код не срабатывает, не могу точно сказать ничего, но toggleClass() по идеи должна принимать строку/название класса, мб то что вы пытаетесь передавать туда функцию и есть ошибкой.